# I cant migrate and run my server successfully in django

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I am getting an error whenever i want to migrate and run my server in Django.

```
     File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 195, in connect
        self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 227, in get_new_connection
        return Database.connect(**conn_params)
```

Comment: Looks like you're not connected to your database.

Comment: How do i do that ?

Comment: https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/connect-to-mysql-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the default database?

Here are the django docs for setting up the database
[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial02/#database-setup)

Comment: Gone through it but wasnt helpful.

Comment: No, I am not using default db,  I am using mysql